# PowerShell Script to find if a Folder Exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I want a script to find if a Folder Exists (I should be able to provide the Folder Name), it should automatically look at all the Drives and output the full Path.

I  already tried test-path and I tried this

```
$folder = Get-ChildItem $Reports -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
If ($Folder) { 'folder exists'} 
else { 'no folder there'}
```

This will show just folder exists or not, what i am looking for is when i provide a Folder Name (for ex: Reports) it should look in all the Drive and Output the full Path (for ex: c:\Windows\Reports)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't how we ask questions around here. Read this [guideline page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can check out the [powershell documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/powershell/topics) to get yourself started on the language. Just don't expect people to write programs for you here.

Comment: I am not Excepting people to write a code for me, I  was just trying to get some help as i am new to powershell, i had few ideas which are not working as expected so thought if i post just a question people can give some ideas and i can work from there. rather me posting some random code for people to guess.

Comment: understandable, and I'm sorry for the downvote outrage that happens on questions like yours. However, it is somewhat necessary for beginners to learn how things work on Stack Overflow so that they can learn from their mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment above says, take a look at the guidlines and powershell documentation.

FWIW, what you're looking for is a really basic cmdlet already built into powershell called Test-Path, which you can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Test-Path?view=powershell-5.1)

here is a simple example:

`test-path -Path C:\Windows`

If you're really new to powershell, run through some tutorials and videos to get started.

Edit: sounds like OP is actually trying to do the following:

- There are folder(s) named "Report" that could live in different place
- They are trying to run a script to find those folder and write out their path

You could iterate over all the drives on a machine and search everything. This might be very slow, though.

```
$drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem
foreach($drive in $drives)
{
    dir -Path $drive.Root -Recurse -Directory -include *Reports -name -ea SilentlyContinue
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your Reponse sambardo, i already tried test-path and i tried this $folder = Get-ChildItem $Reports -Directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
If ($Folder) 
{ 'folder exists'}
else
{ 'no folder there'},   what i am looking is when i provide a Folder Name (for ex: Reports) it should look in all the Drive and written the full Path (for ex: c:\Windows\Reports)

Comment: @Megna, you should put code like that in your question so that we can comment on it. That will make the question already so much better because you have clearly tried and you have a fixable problem.

Comment: @Megna, I edited the code you put in the OP into an actual code block, but I'm not understanding what your explanation is saying. If you can clarify your goal we might be able to help.

Comment: I have a Folder called "Reports" but on my server there are 4 Drive (C,D,E,& F), I want a script to go check all the Drives for "Reports" Folder and output the Path (like C:\Reports or E:\Test\Reports etc), i want the path where "Reports" Folder Exists on the Server. Hope this helps. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Megna, see my edit, I think this addresses what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sambardo, This helps a lot build a script,I need to make couple of changes

Comment: No problem, glad I could help